# Implementing 3 stacks in one Array using C++

Tags: c++, stack

Was wondering how this can be done using C++.

Divide given array into 3 parts  - (0 - N/3), (N/3 - 2N/3) , (2N/3 - N). How would i keep track of the overflow?

Thanks
Kelly

Comment: So all the stacks are equal in size and are not growable. Right?

Comment: Yes. Lets say the array size is 300.

Answer (score 1):

You must necessarily maintain a pointer-to-top for each of your stacks.  Why not just check that these pointers don't exceed their bounds?

Comment: @Kelly: `void push(int stacknum, T data) { if (top[stacknum] == (N/3)*stacknum) { error("overflow"); } else { /* Push */ } }`.

Comment: Certainly a possibility that way, but if you "sacrifice" one word per stackpart you can avoid having the user keep track of the stacknum somewhere. A negligible overhead for a much nicer API imho.

Comment: @Voo: I was assuming all of this would be encapsulated in a struct somewhere, along with a nice interface that hides all the details!

Comment: @Oli, but how do i find the index of the top element?


I have tried something like this.

In order to maintain the pointer , i have declared another array(not sure if this is the right way)

int *arrayPointer[3] = { NULL, NULL ,NULL }; // Initially pointing NULL

Let size of each stacks be 300, so my array size would be 3 * Size of each stack.
int sizeOfStack = 300;
int *buffer = new int [ 3 * sizeofStack ];

I am blank after this.

void push ( int stackNum, int value)

Comment: @Kelly: You can either maintain pointers, or indices.  Pointers would be: `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { arrayPointer[i] = &buffer[sizeofStack*i]; }`.  Indices would be: `int arrayIndices[3]; for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { arrayIndices[i] = sizeofStack[i]; }`.

Comment: Ok. Would something like this be correct?

int stackSize = 300;
int *array = new int [3 * stackSize];
int *stackPtr = new int [3];

Comment: Ok. Would something like this be correct?

int stackSize = 300;
int *array = new int [3 * stackSize];
int *stackPtr = new int [3];

for ( int i =0 ; i < 3; ++i)
{
   stackPtr[i] = array[i * stackSize];
}

void push( int stackNum ,int value )
{
   if ( array[stackNum] == (sizeof(array)*stackNum ) )
   {
        "OverFlow"
   }
   array[stackNum++] = value;
}